# when performing Unit Testing with Jest in React Js function component getting "symbol is not a function error "

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I am new to React Js and Jest I tried to perform unit testing with jest I am getting the below error.

**DemoContainer.js**

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';

import { AuthContext, UiContext } from 'Stores';

const DemoContainer = () => {
    const { user } = useContext(AuthContext);

    return (
        <div data-testid='demo-container' className='demo__container'>
            <h1>{user}</h1>
        </div>
    );
};

export default memo(DemoContainer);
```

**DemoContainer.test.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import DemoContainer from '../demoContainer';
import { render, fireEvent, cleanup } from '@testing-library/react';
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';

afterEach(cleanup);

it('renders correctly', async () => {
    const mockAction = jest.fn();
    const { getByTestId } = render(<DemoContainer className='demo-container'></DemoContainer>);
    const container = getByTestId('demo-container');
    expect(accAction).toHaveClass('met-accordion__title-box');
});
```

and the error is

[image]

I did explore a lot still not able to find the answer.

Comment: Interesting. Have you ensured all the dependencies are installed? I don't see any overt issue with `render` not being a function in your code.

Comment: its working fine for other components I feel strange why its not working for only few specific components.

Comment: remove the className from "DemoContainer" in the test file. your "DemoContainer" do not need the props

Comment: I did still its same problem